# Updating Unanswered Questions

Tags: discussion, questions

I recently posted a question that discouragingly received only a handful of views and no comments or answer attempts, likely the result of how it addressed an uncommon subject.  I have continued to research the issue mentioned in the posting, and have tried several alternative solutions from additional online searches, but none have been successful.

Typically, updating questions seems to be reserved for significant changes where suggested code snippets are implemented from comments or answers from the community.  Often, though, updates imply further tweaking is required before the question can be fully resolved.

If I were to post frequent status updates from researching my question, most of them would include StackOverflow posts and external links from which I attempted implementing suggestions related to my problem.  But my concern is that these relatively small and unsuccessful changes would be of little benefit to those answering my question.

When is it advantageous to continue updating a question with research updates including new author-made code adjustments that are minimal and unsuccessful?  Would this provide grounds for reinvigorating interest in the question?  Could community members significantly benefit from the additional research and implementations when crafting answers?

Comment: I think it would be OK to update as you continue to research; changing the question once you have answers is problematic, but prior to that if you've more detail to add then please do so.

Comment: Voting to leave open; the question is not getting more attention, but about when to edit the question with results from further research.

Comment: I have voted against the duplicate flag. **That** post is "I want to attract attention to my unanswered question"; **this** post has a different intention.

Comment: _"But my concern is that these relatively small and unsuccessful changes would be of little benefit to those answering my question."_ Ah, but these changes would show potential answerers what you've already attempted, so that they don't repeat things you've already done. That can be beneficial, both to you and to them. (You don't get answers that you already know don't work, they don't waste their time trying something you've already tried.)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Even a result of "this didn't work" improves your question.

Also, if you found that solution 'foo' was specified in question X, but solution 'foo' did not work for you, you should definitely add that to your question - make it clear that your question is not a duplicate of question X.

As @Kendra points out in the comments, these results show what you've already tried, and save time - now potential answerers know that you've already tried this.
Or, a knowledgeable reader may see that you tried to apply a given solution wrongly, and give you the directions to apply it correctly.

It would be wrong to edit your question every minute just to get it bumped; but if you've done some serious experimenting, it will have taken you much more time than that.

How much experimentation is enough to warrant an edit? This remains something to be judged on a case by case basis; but if you've tried a new approach without success, that is definitely worth mentioning in your question.

In short, do edit your question. Even the "this didn't work" is helpful.

Comment: In addition, to keep the question from becoming a huge multi-sectioned document, remember to keep examples to the shortest program necessary to reproduce.